# Determine all $n$-vertex simple graphs $G$ such that every induced subgraph of $G$ with $3$ vertices has either $1$ or $2$ edges.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I got an interesting question in graph theory:

> Let $n \ge 5$. Determine all $n$-vertex simple graphs $G$ such that every induced subgraph of $G$ with $3$ vertices has either $1$ or $2$ edges.

One thing I could understand is that there is no triangle in the graph.

I could not proceed further. Need some help.

Comment: Since then any three vertices form a triangle in the graph $G$ or a triangle in $\overline{G}$, then this problem is equivalent to the Ramsay number problem $R(3,3)$. It is also called the problem about [friends and strangers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_on_friends_and_strangers)

Comment: @kabenyuk: $R(3,3)=6{}{}{}$

Comment: @markvs Yes, of course. Any graph $G$ on $n\geq6$ vertices or its complement $\overline{G}$ contains a triangle, i.e. Ramsey number $R(3,3)\leq6$ (sorry for the typo in that name). Since $\overline{C}_5=C_5$, we have $R(3,3)=6$.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one such graph: a simple cycle with $5$ vertices and $5$ edges.

Every simple graph with $6$ vertices has either a complete induced subgraph or an empty induced subgraph with $3$ vertices. So your $n$ is necessarily $=5$.

Let $n=5$. The graph must have a simple path of length $2$: $a-b-c$. The other two vertices are $d,e$. Then $d$ is connected either to $a$ or to $c$. WLOG $a-d$.

Same for $e$: it must be connected to $a$ or $d$. If $e-a$, then the induced subgraph $\{e,b,d\}$ must be empty, a contradiction. So $c-e$. Thus we have a path $d-a-b-c-e$. But edges $d-b, b-e$ are forbidden and the induced subgraph $\{d,b,e\}$ cannot be empty. Hence we have $d-e$ and we have a cycle $d-a-b-c-e-d$. Any other edge between these vertices gives a complete subgraph with $3$ vertices. So the graph is the cycle with $5$ vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a vertex $v$ of the graph $G$ has degree at least $3$. No pair of  vertices adjacent to $v$ can be joined (or they would form a triangle with $v$) but then the induced subgraph on three of the vertices adjacent to $v$ has no edges.

So every vertex has degree $1$ or $2$. Since $G$ is simple it is either a single chain or a single cycle. The first,third and fifth vertex of a chain of length at least $5$ have no joining edges and so the only solution is a cycle of length $5$.

Comment: The difference with my answer posted 9 hours earlier is that $R(3,3)\le 6$ is not mentioned.

Comment: This proof covers all $n\ge 5$ in one go without needing to quote that result.

Comment: "That result" is a trivial middle school exercise.